# iterate over variable json object in xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-3.0

```
<value-of  select="(//@EscalationHistory)"/>
```

```
<for-each select="(//@EscalationHistory)">
    <span>
    <value-of select="$Title"/>
    </span>
    <span>
    <value-of select="$ID"/>
    </span>
</for-each>
```

I'm trying to loop over json object value , I searched almost every where but no clear solution  most of the approaches not working

I'm using in the html tag the following

```
<html xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"  
      exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
      xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
      version="3.0" lang="en">
```

kindly give me the proper way how to solve this

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing an example of the input, your current stylesheet and the expected output.

Comment: With XSLT 3.0 and JSON represented as XPath 3.1/XSLT 3.0 XDM maps and arrays a path expression like `//@EscalationHistory` doesn't make any sense as that selects attribute nodes; even with the XML representation of JSON you can work with in XSLT 3.0/XPath 3.1 that path doesn't make sense as there you would have `map` or `array` elements or `number` or `string` elements with a `key` attribute.

Comment: You need to show us your "variable JSON object" and your desired output.